# Get multiple elements by id from template in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

This `"myTemplate:: #foo"` will get me the `#foo` element.

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="boo"></div>
<div id="moo"></div>
```

However I want to get `"myTemplate:: #foo, #moo"` but that selector doesn't work.

Is it possible to get multiple elements from template in Thymeleaf by id?

What would be the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

This selector does what you want (verified on thymeleaf 3):

```
"myTemplate :: [id='foo' or id='moo']"
```

[More examples of thymeleaf selectors.](http://www.attoparser.org/apidocs/attoparser/2.0.4.RELEASE/org/attoparser/select/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't select the elements although I've double checked it and used it exactly as described. Can't find the reason yet :( maybe because I'm resolving the template manually in a class method. Anyway thank you +1

Comment: @kidwon -- what do you mean?  Creating your own `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` and `TemplateEngine` and calling `engine.process()`?  How are you calling it?  This works for me: `engine.process("myTemplate", new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("[id='foo' or id='moo']")), ctx);`.  Are you using thymeleaf 3?

Comment: I'm using  `View resolvedView = viewResolver.resolveViewName("myTemplate :: [id='foo' or id='moo']", locale)`;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Thymeleaf use multiple templates. point is th:fragment symbol and th:replace symbol. if you want to more information. you search two keyword.

my sample code.

**content**

```
<!-- start wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- start top header -->
    <div id="header" th:replace="layout/header :: officeHeader"></div>
    <!-- end top header -->
    <!-- start body content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- start left side column -->
        <div id="sidebar" th:replace="layout/left :: officeSidebar"></div>
        <!-- end left side column -->
        <div id="body" th:replace="user/__${content}__:: ${content}"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- end body content -->
</div>
<!-- end wrapper -->
<!-- start footer -->
<div id="footer" th:replace="layout/footer :: officeFooter"></div>
```

**footer**

```
<!-- start footer -->
<footer class="main-footer" th:fragment="officeFooter">

</footer>
<!-- end footer -->
```